# VB.net searching for terms within a string?

Tags: vb.net, string, console, readline

```
    Dim keys1() As String = {"corrupt", "selfish", "power", "lying", "lies", "media"}
    Dim terms1 As Integer = 0
    Dim terms1string As String = ""
    terms1string = Console.ReadLine()
    For Each st As String In keys1
        terms1 = terms1 + 1
    Next
    If terms1 < 2 Then
        Console.WriteLine("yay!")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("YouFail")
    End If
```

Theres my code. I'd like it to be that if your string entered has more than two of those terms, then it writes "Yay"-- otherwise it writes "YouFail."

---update 8/29/12---

```
    Function StageTwo(ByVal fname, ByVal lname, ByVal city)
    Console.WriteLine("Describe the U.S. Government.")
    Dim overall As Integer = 0
    Dim keys1() As String = {"corrupt", "selfish", "power", "lying", "lies", "media"}
    Dim terms1 As Integer = 0
    Dim terms1string As String = ""
    terms1string = Console.ReadLine()
    For Each st As String In keys1
        If InStr(terms1string, st) > 0 Then '<<<this line right here!
            terms1 = terms1 + 1
        End If
    Next
    If terms1 < 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("yay!")
        overall = overall + 1
    End If
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Describe the economic status in the U.S.")
    Dim keys2() As String = {"broken", "backed", "failed", "skewed", "tilted", "99%", "rigged", "unfair"}
    Dim terms2 As Integer = 0
    Dim terms2string As String = ""
    terms2string = Console.ReadLine()
    For Each st As String In keys2
        If InStr(terms2string, st) > 0 Then '<<<this line right here!
            terms2 = terms2 + 1
        End If
    Next
    If terms2 < 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("yay!")
        overall = overall + 1
    End If
    If overall = 2 Then
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a username.")
        Dim username As String = ""
        username = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please wait.")
        IsURLValid(username, overall)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Test Failed.")
    End If
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Function
```

That's my fresh code. Still not working, it's printing test failed after entering corrupt for the first one and broken for the second one. Help again?
Thanks so much guys.

Comment: Have a look at RegEx.  It's a bit of a learning curve, but a definate investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complicated? Just use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx):

```
Dim keys1() As String = {"corrupt", "selfish", "power", "lying", "lies", "media"}
Dim terms1string = Console.ReadLine()

Dim terms1 = keys1.Count(function(key) terms1string like "*" & key & "*")

If terms1 < 2 Then
    Console.WriteLine("yay!")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("YouFail")
End If
```

If you want to match the single words (`foobar power lies` are 2 matches, `foobarpowerlies` are 0 matches), you can use this line instead:

```
Dim terms1 = keys1.Count(function(key) terms1string.Split().Contains(key))
```

---

For completeness, here's a regex version:

```
' generous match ('foobarpowerlies' => 2 matches)
Dim pattern = String.Join("|", keys1)
Dim terms1 = Regex.Matches(terms1string, pattern).Count
```

or

```
' strict match using word boundaries ('foobarpowerlies' => 0 matches, but 'foobar power lies' => 2 matches)
Dim pattern = String.Join("|", keys1.Select(function(key) "\b" & key & "\b"))
Dim terms1 = Regex.Matches(terms1string, pattern).Count
```

Answer (score 2):

Should "Austin Powers" match "power" and should "uncorrupt" match "corrupt"? Assuming "no"
Should "POWER" match "power"? Assuming "yes"

The safest way to do this is with Regex

```
Function WordCount(keys() As String, terms As String) As Integer
    Dim pattern As String = "\b(" + Regex.Escape(keys(0))
    For Each key In keys.Skip(1)
        pattern += "|" + Regex.Escape(key)
    Next
    pattern += ")\b"

    Return Regex.Matches("terms", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count
End Function


Sub Main()
    Dim keys1() As String = {"corrupt", "selfish", "power", "lying", "lies", "media"}
    Dim count As Integer
    count = WordCount(keys1, "lying son of a corrupt . . .") ' returns 2
    count = WordCount(keys1, "Never caught lying and uncorrupt . . .") ' returns 1
End Sub
```

The `Regex.Escape` function ensures that any Regex specific characters in your keys will be escaped, and will not be treated as Regex commands.

The `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option tells it to do a case insensitive match.

The `\b` is a word boundry, so there must be a word boundary (space, punctuation, new line, start of string, end of string etc) before and after the match.

Putting the keys in this structure `(key1|key2|key3)` says it can match on `key1` *or* `key2` *or* `key3`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have something for you.

Your father's INSTR(). This is the weapon of a QuickBasic 4.5 hacker. Not as clumsy or random as a regex; an elegant weapon for a more civilized age.

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim keys1() As String = {"corrupt", "selfish", "power", "lying", "lies", "media"}
    Dim terms1 As Integer = 0
    Dim terms1string As String = ""
    terms1string = Console.ReadLine()
    For Each st As String In keys1
      If InStr(terms1string, st) > 0 Then '<<<this line right here!
        terms1 = terms1 + 1
      End If
    Next st
    If terms1 < 2 Then
      Console.WriteLine("yay!")
    Else
      Console.WriteLine("YouFail")
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()

  End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too simplistic, but if you use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can change your For loop to:

```
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(terms1string) Then
        For Each st As String In keys1
            If terms1string.IndexOf(st) <> -1 Then
                terms1 = terms1 + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

It's simplistic in that it doesn't tokenize the input... so words like "corruption" and "belies" will register a match.  If you need exact matches, take a look at [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get the input words, and then there are a number of algorithmic options to compare that list to your list of keys.